Proof that the underlying group of the free topological group is free
I am studying Arhangel'skii and Tkachenko's book on topological groups. In the chapter on free topological groups they offer a long and involved proof that the underlying group of the free topological group on a Tychonoff space $X$ is the free group on the underlying set of $X$. The problem is, I think I have a proof of this that is much simpler, but the fact that they don't use this simpler proof or comment on its existence suggests to me there is something wrong with it. It is as follows:
Proposition. Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space, so that $F(X)$, the free topological group on $X$, exists. Then the underlying group of $F(X)$ is the free group on the underlying set of $X$.
proposed proof. Let $G$ be a group, and $f:X\to G$ a (set) function. Give $G$ the indiscrete topology, so $G$ becomes a topological group, and $f$ a continuous map. Since $F(X)$ is the free topological group on $X$, there is a continuous homomorphism $\tilde{f}:F(X)\to G$ extending $f$. In particular, $\tilde{f}$ is a homomorphism extending the set function $f$. Since $f:X\to G$ was arbitrary, by the uniqueness of the free group on the set $X$, the underlying group of $F(X)$ is isomorphic to the free group on the set $X$.
Judging by the presentation in the book, it seems like the techniques they use in their proof are independently important, but still the fact that they don't mention this proof suggests to me it is wrong.
Edit: Someone commented earlier, but deleted, that the proposed proof doesn't show that $\tilde{f}$ is the unique such homomorphism. Along similar lines, if there were an easy proof that $\tilde{f}$ is unique, I think the proposed proof might not show that the underlying group of $F(X)$ is canonically isomorphic to the free group.

@Jakobian They don't say G (using the notation in OP) needs to be Hausdorff in their definition, and a different book (Todorcevic's Topics in Topology) doesn't either, and the existence proof doesn't seem to suppose that the target group be Hausdorff either... (Edit to clarify: on the page you're talking about, the target group is $H$, not $G$, and $H$ is not supposed to be Hausdorff.)

@Jakobian In case you miss my edit, in their notation on p. 410 $G$ is the free topological group. In my proof, $G$ is their $H$, which is not assumed to be Hausdorff.

Sorry, yes, you are right. Its the free group that's supposed to be Hausdorff

I think this might be because in the definition of free topological group, $\sigma:X\to F(X)$ is such that $\sigma(X)$ has to generate $F(X)$ topologically and not algebraically. So the thing to check is that indeed does so algebraically. That is, the subgroup generated by $\sigma(X)$ is required to be dense instead of equal to $F(X)$

This should also be connected to showing that $\tilde{f}$ is unique. The function $f:X\to G$ extends to a homomorphism $f:F(X)\to G$, but you can't claim uniqueness unless $X$ algebraically generates $F(X)$ (uniqueness would be obvious if $G$ were Hausdorff - it isn't). So we are back to having to prove theorem 7.1.5 from Topological groups and related structures.
